# Override ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings on runtime, only for the current session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

In certain situations I'm overriding the `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` on runtime:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "address.example.com",
      :port => "123",
      :domain => "example.com",
      :authentication => "login",
      :user_name => "foo",
      :password => "bar"
   }
   super
  end
end
```

It seems that I'm not just setting it for that particular session, but also for sessions to come. How can I avoid that? How can I assure that I'm only changing settings for this session?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can change ActionMailer settings for particular session as a whole, but you can change SMTP settings for one email delivery.

In your mailer you can do something like this:

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def registration(params)
    smtp_settings = {
      :address => "address.example.com",
      :port => "123",
      :domain => "example.com",
      :authentication => "login",
      :user_name => "foo",
      :password => "bar"
    }

    mail(
      to: params[:to], 
      subject: "Welcome", 
      delivery_method: :smtp,
      delivery_method_options: smtp_settings
    )
  end
end
```

`delivery_method: :smtp` param doesn't have to be included if your default email delivery method is SMTP.

This should work as expected. It will override smtp settings for just one mailer in this case. You can send the smtp settings through the params if you want to change it only for one particular email.

Comment: Thanks @edariedl, but that wouldn't work for me, since I'm not sending a mail like that. I'm using Devise and devise handles the emailing...

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 Sorry I was not able to help. Unfortunately I don't think there is some other way how to change SMTP settings. According to ActionMailer source codes you can either change global settings through `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings`, or, as I mentioned above, directly in the Mailer for one email. There is nothing in between these two options.